# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when use pyplot

Tags: python

I have such Python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cmath

X1=np.arange(1,6+0.05,0.05)
X2=np.arange(1,6+0.05,0.05)
[x1,x2]=np.meshgrid(X1,X2)
f=cmath.sqrt(1+x1**2)+cmath.sqrt(1+x2**2); 
plt.contour(x1,x2,f,20) 
plt.show()
```

And such error:

```
File "g:/python-code/numerical-optimization/nt.py", line 9, in <module>
    f=cmath.sqrt(1+x1**2)+x2**2
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

How can I fix?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x1` and `x2` are both of type `np.ndarray`. Therefore, cmath cannot be used on them. Use `np.sqrt` instead of `cmath.sqrt`.